# Force popup to copy paste

Tags: android, android-edittext, popup, copy-paste

On some devices when you long click the text you will get a popup where you can copy or past. While on other devices you are getting a toolbar, with similar options.

Is there some default popup that I can use to replace the toolbar?

### Popup

[image]

### Toolbar

[image]

Comment: What do you want exactly? Remove your popup for another one?